# $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\sin1/x$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

What is
$$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}{\left( \sin{\frac{1}{x}}\right)} $$?

Wolfram says "-1 to 1", but I don't know what that means.

In fact, I thought this limit didn't exist, so what does "-1 to 1" mean in this context?

Comment: This limit does not exist. Wolfram Alpha says so too in parentheses.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers.  I understand what's going on now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For every $a\in[-1,1]$, there is some sequence $(x_{n})$ such that $x_{n}\rightarrow 0$ and $\sin(1/x_{n})\rightarrow a$.

Comment: Of course, so the limit doesn't exist as expected.  It must mean what RRL said.  That is, it "oscillates" between -1 and 1.

Comment: Yes, the function assumes every point in $[-1,1]$ as adherent point.

Comment: In other words, $$-1\leqslant \sin x \leqslant 1,$$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 7):

The limit $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}{\left( \sin{\frac{1}{x}}\right)}$$

does not exist.

Note that as x approaches $0$, $\sin( 1/x )$ covers the closed interval  $[-1, 1]$ infinitely many times.

For example at $ x= \frac {2}{(2n+1)\pi } $ we have $\sin(1/x)=\pm 1.$

Thus there is no limit for $\sin(1/x)$ as $x$ approaches $0$.

Answer (score 6):

$$\Box \ \nexists \lim_{x\to 0}\bigg(\sin\frac1x\bigg).$$ *Proof*: Let $u = \dfrac{1}{x}$ then $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x} = \infty$$ since $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x} = 0.$$ Therefore, we get $$\lim_{x\to 0}\bigg(\sin\frac 1x\bigg) = \lim_{u\to\infty}(\sin u)$$ but this cannot exist because sine is a [periodic fluctuating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_function). $\qquad \qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\,\,\,\,$

Answer (score 5):

When $\frac1x\to\infty$ it can be any value resulting from -1 to 1 because $-1<sin($any real number$)<1$ and the exact **angle** of $\infty$ cannot be determined.

Answer (score 5):

Take $a_n=\dfrac{1}{n\pi}$. Clearly, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$ and $b_n=\dfrac{1}{\frac{1}{2}(4n\pi +\pi)}$. Clearly, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}b_n=0$. Then, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{a_n}\right)=\sin(n\pi)=0$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{b_n}\right)=\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}(4n\pi +\pi)\pi\right)=1$. Thus, the limit doesnt' exist.